# Getting HTTP 401 Error calling MS CRM 365 USING SOAP UI

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to call MSCRM 365 web services using SOAPUI, this is what i have done so far

1. Downloaded Organization WSDL from my cRM instance
2. Uploaded in SOAPUI
3. Added three header parameters - Content-Type, SOAPAction and Accept
4. Added Username and Password in Request Properties

Whenever I send a request to MSCRM, I get "HTTP ERROR 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied"

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Nitesh

Comment: I find it easy to use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) with [Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en): In this way you log in to your browser, and all requests sent from Postman will automatically have the same cookies available. I am not aware if there is a similar solution for SoapUI.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is Dynamics 365 it does not authenticate using Username / Password. Instead you will need to use OAuth as shown in the link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327838.aspx

```
// TODO Substitute your correct CRM root service address, 
string resource = "https://mydomain.crm.dynamics.com";

// TODO Substitute your app registration values that can be obtained after you
// register the app in Active Directory on the Microsoft Azure portal.
string clientId = "e5cf0024-a66a-4f16-85ce-99ba97a24bb2";
string redirectUrl = "http://localhost/SdkSample";


// Authenticate the registered application with Azure Active Directory.
AuthenticationContext authContext = 
    new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common", false);
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, new
                                                       Uri(redirectUrl));
```

Use the access token in message requests:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);  // 2 minutes
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
```

Another options would be to shift from Xrm.Client to Xrm.Tools.Connection. See the example in this site.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602970.aspx